# how to compile the sph_convert.exe in x86

Tags: speech-recognition, speaker

I want to convert some sph files to `wav`, so i download the file `sph_convert_v2_1.zip` from nist.
But the `sph_convert.exe` only can be used in `x86`. I use this `gcc -o sph_convert.exe *.c` in order to  compile it. But this error has occurred：

[image]

please how can i compile it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

you could use sph2pipe instead.

Just download the sph2pipe from here: https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/language-resources/tools/sphere-conversion-tools

And then click the exe file to install it onto your windows.

Later, go to command prompt > just `cd` into the folder that has the EXE file and the `.sph` you want to convert > type in the command

```
sph2pipe.exe file file.wav
```